# Assign javascript object property a value via string value on another object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to assign myShuttle.command to a string called signIn which is being stored in the shuttleCommands function.

```
function buildAndLaunchSignInShuttle (credentialsDoc) {
    var myShuttle = new shuttle();
    myShuttle.command = shuttleCommands.signIn;
    myShuttle.document = credentialsDoc;
    var responseObject = server.launchShuttle(myShuttle);

    return responseObject;
}

function shuttleCommands() {
    return {
        signIn: "signIn",
        signOut: "signOut",
        getEntireCollection: "getEntireCollection",
        getSingleDocument: "getSingleDocument",
        saveDocument: "saveDocument"
    };
}
```

How do I go about doing this?  I don't really know what the right way of phrasing this is which is hindering my Googling!

Comment: `shuttleCommands` is a function. Drop the function ceremony and make it an object literal.

Comment: You have to run `shuttleCommands` first...  `shuttleCommands` is a function.  You have to run it for it to return the object with what you're trying to get.

Comment: Can you give a code example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

```
myShuttle.command = shuttleCommands.signIn;
```

This will assign myShuttle.command to the signIn attribute of the shuttleCommands function itself, which is probably undefined.

I think you want to assign myShuttle.command to the signIn attribute of *the value returned by* the shuttleCommands function, which would be

```
myShuttle.command = shuttleCommands().signIn;
```

Comment: Yup, this is what should happen.

Comment: At first look I thought that was the ticket but I'm getting a TypeError: object is not a function error.  It was a global variable before but I want to wrap it in a function to stop it being global.

Comment: If shuttleCommands isn't a function, what is it?  You might want to learn to use the browser's debugger.

Comment: It's exactly as I've put it above, which is a function as far as I can tell.

Comment: Your computer has a different opinion, and it is usually well-informed about such things.  Investigate with the debugger.